# Split a string a few characters before delimiter in PHP

Tags: php, string, split

```
$test_sample = "AFC Bournemouth4 - 3Liverpool
Halbzeit    0 - 2   

20'     0 - 1   Sadio Mane
(assist) Emre Can
22'     0 - 2   Divock Origi
(assist) Jordan Henderson
48' Jack Wilshere       

50' Simon Francis       

53'         Jordan Henderson
56' Callum Wilson   1 - 2   

64'     1 - 3   Emre Can
(assist) Sadio Mane
76' Ryan Fraser
Benik Afobe (assist)
2 - 3   

79' Steve Cook
Ryan Fraser (assist)
3 - 3   

87'         Emre Can
90' Nathan Ake  4 - 3";
```

So, this is an example I want to split in specific strings. Every line is marked by a timestamp. The lines could be either goals (with the actual result and assist) or yellow/red cards.
My first idea was to preg_split the string by the timestamp. Though there are other numbers in the string, I thought it would be the best way to use " ' " as delimiter here. But therefor I need to jump at least one character before the delimiter to split at the right place, which is my first problem: I don't know how to do this. My guess is preg_split is the wrong function to do the splitting here.

Then I tried just a simpler splitting:

```
$test_strings = preg_split("/[']+/", $test_sample);
```

Besides the problem to have timestamp and text splitted at the wrong place, I encountered my second problem here (which would be a problem, too, even if I were able to cut the string at the right place):

```
0 - 1   Sadio Mane (assist) Emre Can
```

It's easy to split this line into the goalscorer and his assist, but there are lines that look like this, too:

```
Steve Cook Ryan Fraser (assist)
```

Steve Cook is the goalscorer, Ryan Fraser the assist. I don't know how I could split this without errors.

My aim is it to split the example into 1. timestamp, 2. goalscorer, 3. assist and on the other hand into 1. timestamp and 2. player that received a yellow/red card. The code should also identify which team scored a goal or received a card.

You can find the source of the example here if it helps:
http://www.livefootball.com/football/2016-12-04/

Any ideas out there how I could resolve this issues?

Comment: how do you get your samples? Is it just copy/paste from the provided link or do you do a webrequest to get the data?

Comment: Data with no obvious structure is very difficult to manipulate. Can you not get something that has a formal structure to it?

Comment: I just copy/paste from the website. But just because I lack experience and ideas to get the values by other, maybe better ways. And no, right now I don't know any other website that provides this much content and has a better structure to manipulate, too :(

Comment: so if you just copy/paste, you could paste it in MS Excel for example and save the file as ".csv" and then parse this file via PHP. Or you could have a look at PHP's [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get all content from the webpage and then parse this via PHP. (for the second attempt you may have a look [here](https://oscarliang.com/six-ways-retrieving-webpage-content-php/)

Comment: Well, I don't want to use the way by Excel. The solution should be webbased only and at best just a pasting into a form and getting the values with one click. file_get_contents() doesn't work here, I always get a blank site - maybe because the webspace is constructed by Javascript?

Comment: the key point here is that you can't just copy/paste from the page without loosing too much information which is important to parse it. if you do so you get data like your `$test_sample` which is difficult to handle like RiggsFolly already said. At least you should get the javascript code with a webrequest - I think they're blocking any suspicious request... how about writing a browser plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the provided URL and the comments on your question I found a way to query data from `livefootball.com`. The code makes a POST request via `curl` to simulate a browser querying the data - otherwise `livefootball` blocks the query. After getting the sourcecode of the page I try to find any information assigned to the links which you would have to click to get the match-details displayed. This information is stored in the `data-y` parameters of the corresponding links. My next step is to make a webrequest for each of this "keys" to get the detailed information. After this step you should be able to parse the HTML-tables for your desired information!

Here's my code:

```
// maybe you have to change your URL dynamically for the acutal day...
$url = 'http://www.livefootball.com/football/2016-12-04/';
// the following 2 variables are used by curl
$header=array('POST HTTP/1.1');
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0";

// query the url for the page content
$result = getPageContents($url, $header, $agent);
// prepare array for any found keys
$keys = array();
// now iterate through the result to find any "keys"
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($result); )
{
    // search for occurrence of " data-y"
    $i = strpos($result, ' data-y="', $i);
    // if no occurrence was found, strpos returns false, skip the loop
    if($i == false) break;
    // increase $i by the length of ' data-y="'
    $i += 9;
    // search for the closing quotationmark
    $endpos = strpos($result, '"', $i);
    // add the extracted key to your array
    $keys[] = substr($result, $i, $endpos-$i);
    // increase $i to search behind the last found key
    $i += $endpos-$i;
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++)
{
    // query livefootball for the detailed match information
    $result = getPageContents(getUrlFromId($keys[$i]), $header, $agent);

    // now $result contains an HTML-table containing the information you desire
    // HTML-parsing here...
}

// this function handles the POST-request via curl
// returns page content from $url
function getPageContents($url, $header, $agent)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
// this function returns the URL which has to be queried for the detailed match information
function getUrlFromId($id)
{
    $id = str_replace("f", "", $id);
    return 'http://www.livefootball.com/eng/scores/soccer/id/' . $id . '/?fmt=html';
}
```

If there are any questions left, feel free to ask.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for all your help! I'll test the code anytime soon and will let you know if there are any questions.